# MYSQL: Select statement that counts event in timestamp column for the current date adjusting for UTC

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, timestamp-with-timezone

So this has been the biggest pita... My db is in UTC and I am trying to create a select statement that accurately displays the count of newly created customers today in my TZ. The first interval works as intended, but when the clock strikes 5pm PST (UTC -7) and the db switches over to the next day, the second part after the and clause fails, and I am left with an empty set. Tweeked the hell out of the second part but have had no success. Any help would be most appreciated!

SELECT count(*) FROM product36.associate where date(created_date - interval 7 hour) >= curdate() and date(created_date + interval 17 hour) >=curdate();